# Prevent Google Photos to ask for backing up app folders

Tags: java, android, google-photos

I am making a chat app that stores sent images in it's private folder on external storage. After saving an image the Google Photos app notices that and asks if the user wants to backup that folder.

Is there a way to prevent that?

'.nomedia' file does not help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Shank's first solution worked for me.

However, I noticed that I created .nomedia file wrong, so after fixing it the backup problem has been also solved.

Answer (score 1):

Kindof, Google backup reads imgs and video types.

There are 3 workarounds that I know,

1. Make the Folder hidden.

   - Add "." before the folder name. (when u create the folder)
2. Have a lot of folder hierarchy.

   - Example: /0/AppName/sentimgs/  <- Can be read by google backup
   - /0/AppName/bla/bla/bla/sentimgs/   <- Cant be read.
3. Save the img without an extension. And make ur app add it when they want to view it.

Comment: The first solutions works. Thanks! However, I noticed that I created .nomedia wrong, so after fixing it the backup problem has been also solved.